# Некоректо работает routing Angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing

У мня есть главная страница , где находиться контент и

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

На странице есть 2 кнопки логин и регистрация, под них написал роуты:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: AuthComponent, children:[
    {path: 'login' , component: LoginComponent },
    {path: 'registration' , component: RegistrationComponent }
  ]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Проблема состоит в том что когда перехожу по роутах контент страницы логина и регистрации  , подргужаеться на главную страницу в тег роутер-аутлет, как сделать так чтоб например при адресе *****/login у меня загружался отдельный компонент Auth(например) и в нево уже в зависимости нужная страница!

Comment: создай, пожалуйста, пример на codesandbox или stackblitz :)

Comment: Также и у меня на главную страницу подружаеться контент их логин компонента
https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-prg6f

Comment: спасибо за пример. Теперь давай по порядку, что бы ты хотел достичь? какая поставленная цель? Я просто не совсем понял последний вопрос твой  > `ак сделать так чтоб например при адресе *****/login у меня загружался отдельный компонент Auth(например) и в нево уже в зависимости нужная страница!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну как вариант можно на оба запроса login и registration вызывать компонент AuthComponent, далее читать route data, и в зависимости от этого выводить нужный компонент. Т.е. на входе в AuthComponent будет проверка пути и все. Далее обычный if else.
В роуте примерно так.

```js
{path: 'login' , component: AuthComponent, data : {page: 'login'}},
{path: 'registration' , component: AuthComponent, data : {page : 'registration'}}
```

P.S. только не ясно зачем это нужно.